# Applying pdf watermark at typescript side

Tags: typescript, pdf, watermark

I am trying to add a watermark to pdf and image files that I show at the frontend where I use angular with typescript.

I could not find a module that I could use for pdf. I found that on node side there is a library that I tried to use using image-watermark "const watermark = require('image-watermark');" but it seems that require does give me an error when I run ng serve -o. I used the follwoing github source https://github.com/luthraG/image-watermark  [image]

Comment: I install the modules Ghostscript and imagemagick but I still have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I install the modules Ghostscript and imagemagick but I still have the same error. I download the executable file gs920w64.exe which I think the same  asgswin32c.exe from https://ghostscript.informer.com/download/ but still I have an error. I need to add watermark to pdf to prevent the user of my webapplication from taking images and pdf files and use it to prove their ownership of other users asset. I used the library pdfjs and I think I could add watermark to pdf. You can add     "pdf-lib": "^1.17.1",
to package.json file and use library to watermark pdf that located at your remote host using the following code as a function at typescript.

```
     async modifyPdf(url2:string) {
  const url = 'Your remote host url' + url2;
  console.log(url);
  const existingPdfBytes = await fetch(url).then(res => res.arrayBuffer())

  const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes)
  const helveticaFont = await pdfDoc.embedFont(StandardFonts.Helvetica)

  const pages = pdfDoc.getPages()
  const firstPage = pages[0]
  const { width, height } = firstPage.getSize()
  firstPage.drawText('This text was added with JavaScript!', {
    x: 5,
    y: height / 2 + 300,
    size: 50,
    font: helveticaFont,
    color: rgb(0.95, 0.1, 0.1),
    rotate: degrees(-45),
  })

  const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save()
  var blob = new Blob([pdfBytes], { type: "application/pdf" });
  const docUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  window.open(docUrl);
```

}

at angular part you add a link and use this function when you click on it
<a  (click)="modifyPdf(url)" >any text to click on